# Android Studio - if else statement for beginner of Android Studio

Tags: java, android

How do i do an **if statement** for example if the user is from A for the first time, he will do activity a, but if he has been to A before he will go straight to B?

Comment: the default activity will always be A

Comment: Trying to do that will be impossible unless you know how to use databases

Comment: But since you are a beginner it will be difficult

Comment: You can use the firebase realtime database to store whether the user has been there for the first time

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be using a SharedPreference for that case... you could check if preference was set or not to redirect user to activity you want and once the user goes to activity A you set the preference so next time you check will be setted and you go to activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio uses standard Java syntax for if/then/else statements:

```
if (boolean expression) {
// do something
} else if (boolean expression) {
// do something else
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Your boolean expression will vary depending on what you're trying to evaluate. One trick I learned is to not use an "==" operator on strings, instead use strString.equals("value") to get a proper T/F response.

Specific example:

```
if (intVar == 1) {
printf("Hello World 1");
} else if (intVar == 2) {
printf("Hello World 2");
} else {
printf("Hello World 3");
}
```